# Angular 2 get request with headers

Tags: angular

I have come across couple of posts, and I found that we can set headers in get request using code below:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });
headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this._http
  .get(this._url,options)
  .map(res => console.log(res));
```

But in my API if I am doing `console.log(req.headers.authorization)` I am getting undefined. Please let me know what I am missing here.

Updates:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
            .set("X-CustomHeader", "custom header value");
console.log(headers); 
this.users = this.http
    .get(
        "https://reqres.in/api/users",
        {headers})
    .do(console.log)
    .map(data => console.log(data));
```

In code above I am getting headers as shown below:
[image: HTTP Headers]
And on Web API I am getting header as: `'access-control-request-headers': 'authorization'`.
Issue is I am not getting value of authorization token that I am passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
            .set("X-CustomHeader", "custom header value")
            .set("XX","VALUE");
```

> Notice that we are building the HttpHeaders object by chaining
>   successive set() methods. This is because HttpHeaders is immutable,
>   and its API methods do not cause object mutation. Instead, a call to
>   set will return a new HttpHeaders object containing the new value
>   properties.

**Update**

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
            .set("X-CustomHeader", "custom header value");

this.users = this.http
    .get(
        "https://reqres.in/api/users",
        {headers})
    .do(console.log)
    .map(data => console.log(data));
```

For more info you can check this [`link`](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/services)

Comment: Can you please let me know then how to pass these headers with request?

Comment: Thanks Rahul. But still I am not getting header on service.

Comment: can you replicate this issue as this works and the link uses the same

Comment: It would be bit difficult as I cant create express server in stackoverflow.

Comment: what is the error you are getting , i was telling you if you can replicate in something like stackblitz

Comment: If i am doing console.log(request.headers) . In headers I am not getting authorization header if I call from angular. But if I call same API using postman I am getting authorization header in console.log statement

Comment: i donot get what are you trying to acheive where are you trying to log the headers , can you make a interceptor and log the request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162164/discussion-between-rahul-singh-and-tavish-aggarwal).

Comment: @TavishAggarwal i have updated the answer , you need to append the set instead of individual set

Answer (score 1):

If you want headers from your server api you need to add observe to your angular http request.
Angular 5 examples:

```
const options = { observe: 'response' };
this.http.get<ResultResponse>(serverApiUrl, options)
  .pipe(
    map((res: HttpResponse) => {
      console.log(res.headers);
      console.log(res.headers.get('Content-Disposition'));
      return res;
    })
  );
```

If you want to add (multiple) headers to your angular http request:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password));
const options = { headers };
return this.http.get<any>('/service/login', options)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
```

Comment: Still I am facing issue. I have updated my question.